# Can Not Run my Android App in device and simulator in mac

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

adb start-server
adb kill -server
i tried but not working.
find below log .
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.adbimpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService.checkState(AdbDeviceFileSystemService.java:221)
at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.adbimpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService.getDevices(AdbDeviceFileSystemService.java:215)
at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerController.refreshDeviceList(DeviceExplorerController.java:243)
at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerController.access$300(DeviceExplorerController.java:101)
at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerController$ServiceListener.serviceRestarted(DeviceExplorerController.java:449)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.adbimpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService$DebugBridgeChangeListener.lambda$bridgeChanged$1(AdbDeviceFileSystemService.java:232)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:828)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:330)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:134)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:190)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:976)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:843)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:454)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:773)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:453)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:828)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:501)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: What do you mean?  From your question title, it meant that you couldn't run your application, but from the description, seems that the log is related to `adb`, the `adb` couldn't work.

Comment: yes , issue of Adb .  in terminal device found but in android studio device not display.
i uninstall studio and reinstall it but still, the issue is the same.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Even after uninstall and reinstall I cannot get it to work. It was working before. Oh gawd...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to start a new project. Since I was only using the emulator for testing via Expo (I'm building a React Native app), I simply went to File > New Project.

The new project has a working emulator